# Remove hashtags from beginning and end of tweets in R

Tags: r, regex, tweets

I am trying to remove hashtags from beginning of strings in R.
For example:

```
 x<- "I didn't know it could be #boring. guess I need some fun #movie #lateNightThoughts"
```

I want to remove the hashtags at the end of string which are #lateNightThoughts and #movie. Result:

```
 - "I didn't know it could be #boring. guess I need some fun"
```

I tried :

```
stringi::stri_replace_last_regex(x,'#\\S+',"")
```

but it removes only the very last hashtag.

```
- "I didn't know it could be #boring. guess I need some fun #movie "
```

Any idea how to get the expected result?

Edit:

How about removing hashtag from beginning of text ?
eg:

```
x<- "#Thomas20 I didn't know it could be #boring. guess I need some fun #movie #lateNightThoughts"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
>  x<- "I didn't know it could be #boring. guess I need some fun #movie #lateNightThoughts"
> sub("\\s*\\B#\\w+(?:\\s*#\\w+)*\\s*$", "", x)
[1] "I didn't know it could be #boring. guess I need some fun"
```

Or, if you do not care about the context of the first `#` you want to start matching from, you may even use

```
sub("(?:\\s*#\\w+)+\\s*$", "", x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bAIQd2/1).

**Details**

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\B` - right before the current location, there can be start of string or a non-word char (this is usually used to ensure you do not match `#` inside a "word", so if you do not need it, you may remove this non-word boundary)
- `#` - a `#` char
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars  (letters, digits or `_`)
- `(?:\s*#\w+)*` - zero or more occurrences of:

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `#` - a `#` char
  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks, the first regex is working. What if I need to remove hashtag in the beginning of text as well? I updated the question.

Comment: @ZahraHnn This is even easier, [`sub("^(?:\\s*#\\w+)+\\s*", "", x)`](https://regex101.com/r/bAIQd2/3).